# PHP - VAT calculation issue on decimals

Tags: php

Trying to manage product pricing on my database, but got "rounding issues".

My user enters It's "product price" including VAT.
User enters "100,00" to the field,

And I save it to database excluding VAT. (Vat 18%)
100/1.18 = 84,7457. (My database has 2 decimals)

There's 2 options to make calculation:

1. Round down, and result will be 84,74.
2. Round up, and result will be 84,75.

After I make a record to database, I must show product price on front end including VAT.

If my value on database becomes 84,74 I must show it like;
84.74*1.18 = 99,9932
And result will be: 99,99.

If my value on database is 84,74
Result will be 84.75*1.18 = 100,005 (and it will round it to 100,01)

So I couldn't solve that rounding problem.
What's the best way?

If I use "round up" standard on everywhere, then I will calculate wrong.
If I use "round down" standard on everywhere, It will be wrong so.

I tryied "no decimal, only integer" methods, but result doesnt change.
Same problem continues: Which standard I must use.

Comment: What if you store 2 prices: with vat and without it.

Comment: It may cause some accountant problems, because of rounding, I guess.

Comment: "It may cause some accountant problems" --- how? You need to store something anyway. Nevertheless, it does not look like a *technical* problem anymore: if it causes accounting problems - ask your accountant how to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store more decimals, that will do the trick I think. Also, you should/could store the VAT value in the database and instead of recalculating with the percentage, just add the vat value to the stored price to get 100?

Because that way you have  84,75 + 15,25 = 100

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would suggesting storing the original value so that should there be an error with your calculations, whilst simple, you can re-calculate it in the future. You can then store the VAT percentage with the record.

If you need to save the calculated VAT to the DB, do it with a higher number of places. This will allow your accountants to use the numbers how they need without intervention.